# Tera-WURFL: Couldn't fetch mysqli

Tags: php, wurfl

I'm trying to deploy my website to production and I'm getting the following issues using Tera-WURFL:

```
Warning (2): mysqli::real_escape_string() [http://php.net/mysqli.real-escape-string]: Couldn't fetch mysqli [/var/www/fonykweb/public_html/tera-wurfl/DatabaseConnectors/TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL4.php, line 401]
Warning (2): mysqli::query() [http://php.net/mysqli.query]: Couldn't fetch mysqli [/var/www/fonykweb/public_html/tera-wurfl/DatabaseConnectors/TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL4.php, line 258]
Warning (2): TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL4::getDeviceFromCache() [http://php.net/terawurfldatabase-mysql4.getdevicefromcache]: Couldn't fetch mysqli [/var/www/fonykweb/public_html/tera-wurfl/DatabaseConnectors/TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL4.php, line 259]
```

It runs properly on my 2 local machines. The mysqli.so extension is enabled in my php.ini file. What else could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for any poor souls who have lost their way with this issue: The problem ended up being my database user configuration, the user I had set in the Tera-WURFL config file didn't match the user in my database. Once I corrected my database user the problem was solved.